# Decompressing Restcalls using RestSharp in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gzip, restsharp, deflate

I'm trying to make a single automated test that tests for decompression. But I've read online that visual studio automatically decompresses rest responses.

What I have:

```
public Response<TResponse> ExecuteRequest(IRestRequest request)
{
 var response = RestClient.Execute(request);
 var responseDto = (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) ? DeserializeResponse(response.Content) : DeserializeErrorResponse(response.Content);
 return responseDto;
}
```

Where the rest client is the basic RestSharp rest client. But this doesn't return anything about the statistic of the call.

```
TestRequest.AddHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip")
```

Doesn't work either :P

The responses are compressed through fiddler, but is there a way to automate testing this?